# Find the maximum number of purple cars possible in the given sequence of N cars.(See description)

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures

There are N cars in a row numbered from 1 to N. 
A person takes M photographs of cars. For each photograph, the cars appearing in it are given by tuple (i, j), which means all the cars from ith car to jth car will appear in that photograph.

Note that, all the photos need not cover every car. A car can appear in more than one photograph.

It is given that each photograph contains **exactly 1** purple car. Find the maximum number of purple cars possible. If not possible print -1.

Input : First line contains N and M. Next line contains M pairs (x, y) which represent a photograph containing cars from xth car to yth car.
Output : Maximum number of purple cars possible.

Example :

**Input**:

5 1

(3 5)

**Output** : 3

Explanation : only one car from 3 to 5 can be purple. Car 1 and car 2 will be purple for maximizing the number of purple cars.

**Input**:

5 1

(4 4)

**Output** : 5

**Input**:

5 3

(1 4), (3 5), (3, 4)

**Output** : 1

Explanation : Either 3 or 4 can be a purple car.

**Input**:

5 2

(1, 4), (2, 5)

**Output** : 2

Explanation: Car 1 and Car 5 can be purple.

**Input** :

10 3

(1 5), (6, 10), (1, 10)

**Output**: -1

Explanation: It is impossible in this case for each interval to have exactly 1 purple car.

Comment: Provide link to contest (And please make your question **readable**)

Comment: Please show us your approach to the problem.

Comment: Although I cannot yet see a solution clearly, let's collect some observations. 1. Each car which is not contained in an interval can be colored purple. 2. In each interval which does not intersect other intervals, exactly one car can be colored purple. 3. In each interval which is inclusionwise minimal, exactly one car can be colored purple (which is a generalization of 2.) - I believe this can be somehow used to recursively count the cars.

Comment: @f_puras I was able to figure out the things mentioned by Codor, then tried building solution using Dynamic programming and graph algorithm, but without success

Comment: Any constraint? How large is N and M? if you coded smt, you should put it here. Otherwise, if this problem comes from a contest, it will have its tutorial ( in most of the case), so, please give us some reason why we need to solve this problem again for you?

Comment: @PhamTrung I faced this question few days back in a recruitment test. I couldn't solve it that time. Range for N and M wasn't specified. I found the question interesting, hence I am looking for its solution. Any solution better that brute-force would do.

Comment: Your question is valid (in my opinion), please provide your code, or even better, pseudo-code, otherwise, this question will be closed very soon.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, the problem can be solved as a network problem as follows.

The node set of the network has a source node `s` and a terminal `t`; imagine the sink at a leftmost position and the terminal in the righmost position and the flow goes from left to right. Next to `s` put a node for each car and connect `s` to every car. Next to the car nodes create a node for each interval. Now start at the car nodes and create paths to `t`, traversing the interval node set; the path goes through every interval which contains the car.

Except for `s` and `t`, the flow in each node is restricted to be exactly `1` which models that exactly `1` car per interval must be colored purple; the arcs do not explicitly need to be constrained. Finally via some network flow algorithm, maximize the intensity of the flow from `s` to `t`. Color each car purple for which its node has a nonzero flow. If the instance does not permit a feasible flow, the initial problem instance is infeasible.

Comment: @Codor yes they may be identical intervals for example

Input 

5 2

(3, 5),(3,5)

Output: 3

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz in the case of (1 5) (6 10) (1 10) where N=10, output should be -1. I updated the question wiki for the same.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz You are right; the approach does probably not work. I will think it over and update my question; perhaps modelling a matching is too much simplification, I should try a network flow problem.

Comment: I have completely changed the modelling.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that, if there is a photograph which is totally covered by another photograph, we only need to care about the outer photograph(trivial).

Second observation:

For now, after removing all **covered** photographs (as stated above), we will be left with cases like this:

We have n photographs, it can be divided into several clusters, with each cluster is a group of m photographs: `(a1, b1) , (a2, b2) ... , (am, bm)` with `a1 < a2 and b1 > a2 ... or ai < a(i + 1) and bi > a(i + 1)`

We notice that, it is always optimal if we select the first purple car for the first photograph to be in the range `(a1, a2)`, and continue to select car in this manner (the first range which is not yet covered by any car). Prove:

- if we select car in range `(a1, a2)`, so the next car can be selected will be in range `(b1 , bm)`, otherwise, if we choose other car (in range `(a2,b1)`), the range to select next car will be smaller range (trivial to see), so , select car in range `(a1, a2)` will give optimal result.

If we implement a sweep line algorithm, time complexity will be **O(m log m)**

**Note**: this algorithm is valid only if the set of photographs is valid, otherwise, we need to check for its validity.

**Update** : As pointed out by PeterdeRivaz,  we need to take care of one special case: when there are two or more photographs, both cover one photographs, so, we need to join all of them.

Comment: Consider (1 5) (3 4) (2 10).  The middle interval is completely covered, but cannot be ignored because it changes the answer from 2 with your algorithm to 1.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz Good point, take time for me to notice :) Maybe I need to handle this as a special case: If two or more photographs both cover one photograph, so we need to joined these two.

Comment: I think the special case is being handled during cluster formation. If range A fully covers range B, then range A can be removed, recursively. (1 5) (3 4) (2 10) reduces to (3 4) (2 10) which again reduces to (3 4), leaving only one cluster.